# The options.display.max_rows in pandas only shows a summary when truncation happens

Tags: pandas, jupyter-notebook

I have a dataset with 200 rows.  When setting

```
pd.options.display.max_rows = 200
```

we see all rows in a scrollable area:

[image]

But if we set it to less than the full dataset -thus requiring truncation - then we get a summary . and only ***10*** rows ?

```
pd.options.display.max_rows = 100
```

[image]

How can the options be set to really display 100 rows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that this behavior is intended to be controlled as much as it can be by `display.large_repr`:

```
display.large_repr : 'truncate'/'info'
    For DataFrames exceeding max_rows/max_cols, the repr (and HTML repr) can
    show a truncated table (the default from 0.13), or switch to the view from
    df.info() (the behaviour in earlier versions of pandas).
    [default: truncate] [currently: truncate]
```

The default `truncate` gives the present behavior.  `info` does not even give any data at all:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 200 entries, 0 to 199
Columns: 3 entries, column to column_val_cnt
dtypes: int64(1), object(2)
memory usage: 4.8+ KB
```

So there does not appear to be any way to achieve what I'm looking for.

Reference:  [Pandas Display Configurations](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/options.html)

Btw   I also looked into an indirect way to get what I was looking for

```
from IPython.display import display, HTML, Markdown
```

This did not work either.  I'm getting close to "calling it a day" on this feature as "not supported".